# React testing library fimding multiple nodes in the DOM

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am writing tests for my component using react testing library and I am using nested describe blocks for separating tests

```
    const dummyData1 = Array.from({ length: 10 }).map((obj, i) => ({title: "Test" + i,
  value: "Test" + i,
  key: "Test" + i,
}));
describe("Custom Select", () => {
  describe("Single", () => {
    afterAll(() => {
      cleanup();
    });
    const loadMore = jest.fn();
    const onChange = jest.fn();
    loadMore.mockResolvedValueOnce(dummyData2);
    const { queryByTestId, getByText, getAllByText, container } = render(
      <MultiSelect
        data={[{ title: "Test", key: "Test", value: "Test" }, ...dummyData1]}
        value="Test"
        loadMoreData={loadMore}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    );
    const selectWrapper = queryByTestId("multi-select-wrapper");

    it("Renders successfully -- Single", () => {
      expect(selectWrapper).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it("Value rendered -- Single", () => {
      expect(getByText("Test")).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
    it("Options rendered -- Single", async () => {
      act(() => {
        fireEvent.click(selectWrapper);
      });
      const elements = getAllByText("Test");
      expect(elements).toHaveLength(1);
    });

    it("Load More called -- Single", async () => {
      act(() => {
        fireEvent.click(selectWrapper);
      });

      const menuEl = container.querySelector(".multi-select-menu");
      act(() => {
        fireEvent.scroll(menuEl, { target: { scrollY: 700 } });
      });
      await waitFor(
        () => {
          expect(loadMore).toBeCalled();
        },
        { timeout: 500 }
      );
    });
    it("onChange called -- Single", async () => {
      act(() => {
        fireEvent.click(selectWrapper);
      });

      const menuItem = getByText("Test0");
      act(() => {
        fireEvent.click(menuItem);
      });
      await waitFor(
        () => {
          expect(onChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Test0");
        },
        { timeout: 500 }
      );
    });
    it("Load More called on search -- Single", async () => {
      const input = container.querySelector(".multi-select-input");
      act(() => {
        fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "TT" } });
      });
      await waitFor(
        () => {
          expect(loadMore).toBeCalledTimes(1);
        },
        { timeout: 500 }
      );
    });
  });
  describe("Multiple", () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
      cleanup();
    });
    const loadMore = jest.fn();
    const onChange = jest.fn();
    loadMore.mockResolvedValueOnce(dummyData2);
    const { queryByTestId, getByText, getAllByText, container } = render(
      <MultiSelect
        data={[{ title: "Test", key: "Test", value: "Test" }, ...dummyData1]}
        value={["Test"]}
        loadMoreData={loadMore}
        onChange={onChange}
        multiple
        showCheckboxes
      />
    );
    const selectWrapper = queryByTestId("multi-select-wrapper");

    it("Renders successfully", () => {
      expect(selectWrapper).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it("Value rendered", () => {
      expect(getByText("Test")).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });
});
```

I am getting this error on running the tests. The tests run perfectly if I use them separately. I dont want to render in each test individually but the nested describe is not working

`TestingLibraryElementError: Found multiple elements by: [data-testid="multi-select-wrapper"]`

Comment: Is it for watch mode? https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup/#auto-cleanup-in-mochas-watch-mode

Comment: No this is for simple jest testing

Comment: I'm surprised. May you try with adding `afterEach(() => { cleanup(); })` at the very top level `describe()`?

Comment: @skyboyer I tried but its still not working

Comment: It's good practice to call `render` on every test case, and have any common initial setup in a `beforeEach` block. If you want to avoid duplication, move `render(<MultiSelect ... />)` to a separate function, and call the function on every test case.